# Catch url contents and redirect page

Tags: php, html, url, redirect

I have a url setup like

```
mysite.com/QR?id=12345
```

Where id will be some num. I want to be able to browse to this url, take the id value and redirect the page to a different url.

Can I do this with PHP? The ID will also correspond to an ID in my DB.

EDIT: REVISE MY ORIGINAL QUESTION.
What I have is a url to a nonexistent page where ID can be any number. I need to a way to browse to take that url and extract the id value and redirect to a new page where I will display content based on that ID which will have a corresponding value in my DB.

Comment: The short answer is "yes" ... the id value will exist in PHP's $_GET superglobal : `$_GET['id']` - once you've got it you can do whatever you like with it, match on the database, redirect to another page using a `header('Location: ... ')` type call, whatever.

Comment: Will I be able to use a single php file for all urls id=XXXXX?

Comment: Like the url will not exist is my issue. I just want to extract the id and redirect.

Comment: You'll need a PHP file to "be" that "QR", 2 easy ways to do it are to call the file `index.php` and put it in a folder called `QR` but that makes it case-sensitive on a *nix server and `/qr?id=12345` won't work OR you can use an Apache Mod Rewrite to redirect to that PHP file...

Answer (score 3):

```
// First check if it exists
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = someSecurityFunction($_GET['id']);        

    // Check what the value is of ID
    switch ($id)
    {
        case '12345':
            header("Location: website.com?...");
            exit();
        case '67890':
            header("Location: website.com?...");
            exit();
        default:
            echo "No corresponding ID value found...";
            break;
    }

    // Or just redirect to another page and handle there your ID existence thing
    // by omitting the switch-case and redirect at once
    // header("Location: website.com?id=$id");
}
else
{
    echo "No ID found in querystring...";
}
```

Might **this** answer your question?

Comment: I think this is close, I don't necessarily need to know the value of the ID. What will happen is once I have the ID, I will redirect to a page that displays content based on that ID that I reference in a DB.

Comment: @MickB So you want to redirect to a page with the ID? Check my answer, I've editted it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) == '12345'){
    header('Location: example.com');
}
```

I guess something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you'll need a single PHP file to receive the data at `mysite.com/QR` - this can be done by either creating a PHP file called `index.php` and putting it in a `/QR` directory or using Apache ModRewrite (assuming you're running an Apache server).

The advantage of using the `/QR` directory approach is that it's easy - the downside is that it's case-sensitive, `mysite.com/qr?id=12345` will result in a 404 error.

To use Apache ModRewrite you'll need to create or edit a `.htaccess` file in the root of your web tree (or in httpd-vhosts.conf, though yeah, that requires a lot more permissions and maintaining it requires a server reboot) and in that `/.htaccess` file you'll need to point to the PHP file that will handle your QR code redirects - `qr.php`, for example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^QR/?$ /qr.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

- NC = No Case (makes it case insensitive so `/QR` or `/qr` will work
- QSA = Query String Append so that `id=12345` is passed to `/qr.php`
- L = Last, no redirects will be processed after this one if it's valid

Your `/qr.php` file will need to do something like:

```
if(empty($_GET['id'])) {
  // deal with exceptions where the 'id' isn't set
}
else {
  $iId = (int) $_GET['id']; // may as well cast it to an INT if it's matching an auto-incremented database id

  //possibly connect to the database, validate the id, update some records and retrieve the redirection URL
  // ... then redirect
  header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
  header('Status: 303 See Other'); # for Chrome/FastCGI implementation
  header('Location: ' . $sSomeRedirectionURLFromTheDatabase);
  die(); # I generally always die after redirecting
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Actually `/qr.php` might be better served as being the page that displays the content as long as you're **NOT** updating anything in the database (otherwise page reloads will count towards hits if you're logging it in the db, that kind of thing) - use Apache ModRewrite to redirect to it (as outlined before), then manage the output in `/qr.php`

```
if(empty($_GET['id'])) {
  // deal with exceptions where the 'id' isn't set
}
else {
  $iId = (int) $_GET['id'];
  // connect to the database, validate the id and retrieve the relevant
  // content that you want to display (based on the id) and then output it.
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this solution will work. My only concern is that it when I browse to the url it I would get a page error instead of a loaded content page.